# JAVA_HOME not found Maven Docker image Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am receiving a message that `JAVA_HOME` can't be found or is pointed to a JRE when running the following in a Jenkins Declarative Pipeline.

```
pipeline {
  agent none
  stages {
    stage('Build and Package') {
      agent {
        docker { image 'maven:3.5.2-jdk-8' }
      }
      steps {
        sh 'mvn clean verify'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the error message: Running shell script
+ mvn clean verify
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE

Comment: How did you solve at last?

Answer (score -1):

See [Installing Apache Maven](https://maven.apache.org/install.html):

> - Ensure `JAVA_HOME` environment variable is set and points to your JDK installation

Comment: This is within a docker container, not from the filesystem directly.

Comment: @JoshuaAngolano Did you set `JAVA_HOME` in your [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) accordingly?